# Oracle PL/SQL - Bulk Collection usage into WHERE and FROM clause inside conditions and inner views

Tags: oracle, view, pivot, bulk-collect

I have a strange problem using bulk collection as element of FROM clause. 
When I execute this code example, I get, just at run-time, the error "invalid table name".

If I replace the collection with a table everything works well.

Is there any restriction about bulk collection that I'm missing? 
Maybe I cannot use anonymous block in FROM clause?
In the sql debugger I see that l_vol(i) has values but l_vol(i).FIELD doesn't exists.

Thanks.

```
 TYPE t_bulk_vol is table of vol%ROWTYPE;
 l_vol t_bulk_vol;
 ...
 cursor cur is SELECT * FROM vol where ... ;

 OPEN CUR;
 LOOP 
     FETCH CUR BULK COLLECT INTO l_vol;
     ....
     insert into dest
     select col1, col2, ... from 
     (inner view with some pivot, unpivot and l_vol(i).FIELD ...) src where l_vol(i).FIELD = src.FIELD;
```

PS: I cannot paste original code.

Comment: The only thing more fun than debugging somebody's shonky code is debugging somebody's shonky code blindfolded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created the type as you said, but I get the same error at the same point (ORA-00903 - invalid table name).

This is an example of what I've done:

```
  CREATE TYPE REC_VOL AS OBJECT (
       FIELD1    VARCHAR2(25),
       ...
  );
  create TYPE T_BULK IS TABLE OF REC_VOL;
  ....
  l_vol t_bulk;
  ...
```

This is the way I collect the records (I don't use the cursor anymore):

```
    SELECT REC_VOL(FIELD1, ...) BULK COLLECT INTO l_vol
    FROM vol where ...;
```

The exception is still raised at the insert-select statement.

Answer (score 0):

`TYPE t_bulk_vol` is a PL/SQL type.  That means you can only use it in PL/SQL constructs.  You cannot use it in SQL, even if it's SQL in a PL/SQL program.

If you want to use a nested table in the FROM clause of a SELECT you will need to define a SQL TYPE.  This is a pain, because it means you can't use the %ROWTYPE definition (that's a PL/SQL only keyword).  So you'll have to create an object whose signature matches the projection of the table, and then create nested table of that type.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8001.htm#BABHJHEB).

---

Your cursor is defined wrongly.  It should just be a SELECT statement.

```
cursor cur is SELECT * FROM vol where ... ;
```

Save the `BULK COLLECT INTO l_vol` for the actual fetch.

Although presumably this is just a artefact of you faking some PL/SQL because you "cannot paste original code."